# UWP num-pad layout scaling

Tags: c#, xaml, responsive-design, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on creating a num pad that I am going to use to authenticate a door. I am working on creating the ui right now. I am very new to the layout system in WPF and UWP apps. I have a basic layout started, but the buttons don't shrink with the app, and I don't understand how to make the text on the button decrease for smaller screens.

I want to have the numpad on the left side of the screen, and the current entered pin on the right side.

Responsive ui in applications is one of the hardest things for me.

Image:
[image]

XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="btn7" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin" FontStretch="UltraCondensed"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn8" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn9" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" FontSize="50"/>
        <Button Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="AddPin"/>
        <Button Content="Ok" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="PinComplete"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="160" Width="180" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Background="White" FontSize="50" Click="ClearPin"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="NumPadDisplayHint" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Pin" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="PinDisplayValue" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{}{PinValue}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

How do I get the ui to scale properly? And even on smaller screens show the pin above the pin pad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that changes the font size of the controls depending on the size of the Window.
I would recommend that you take a look at visual states https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager. There is a good description on how to use these visual states that change the Layout based upon the current window size. There is also a good description on how to use Resources (which can really save you a lot of unnecessary typing) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references).

```
<Page x:Class="test2_media.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PinButtonStyleNormal">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50" />
        </Style>
        <!-- You can add more Styles like the following to add more visual states-->
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PinButtonStyleSmall" BasedOn="{StaticResource PinButtonStyleNormal}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="small">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <!-- VisualState default -->
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" MinWindowHeight="0"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="btn0.Style" Value="{StaticResource PinButtonStyleSmall}" />
                        <Setter Target="btnOk.FontSize" Value="15" />
                        <Setter Target="btnClear.FontSize" Value="15" />
                        <Setter Target="NumPadDisplayHint.FontSize" Value="15" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <!--customize these states so they resize when and how you want-->
                <VisualState x:Name="normal">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <!-- VisualState to be triggered when window
                         width is >=300 effective pixels or height >=350. -->
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" MinWindowHeight="350"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="btn0.Style" Value="{StaticResource PinButtonStyleNormal}" />
                        <Setter Target="btnOk.FontSize" Value="40" />
                        <Setter Target="btnClear.FontSize" Value="40" />
                        <Setter Target="NumPadDisplayHint.FontSize" Value="40" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="btn0" Content="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{StaticResource PinButtonStyleSmall}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" Grid.Row="2" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn4" Content="4" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn5" Content="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn6" Content="6" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn7" Content="7" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn8" Content="8"  Grid.Column="1" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btn9" Content="9" Grid.Column="2" Click="AddPin" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />

        <Button x:Name="btnOk" Content="Ok" Grid.Row="3" Click="PinComplete" FontSize="15" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" />
        <Button x:Name="btnClear" Content="Clear" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Click="ClearPin" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{Binding Style, ElementName=btn0}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="NumPadDisplayHint" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Pin" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" />
        <TextBox x:Name="PinDisplayValue" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="4" Grid.Row="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1234" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{Binding FontSize, ElementName=NumPadDisplayHint}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you I knew about some of these things but didn't know how to use it.